# Websockets on localhost wihout SSL

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, leap-motion

This line:

```
var socket = new WebSocket(this.getUrl());
```

Causes error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:6437/v6.json' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

I'm guessing I could get around it by using SSL but as I’m just playing around locally with MAMP it would be nice not to have to set this up. I get the same from Chrome, Firefox and Safari. The context is that I’m playing with a Leap Motion controller and everything works fine as long as it’s running remotely with SSL.

Do I really need SSL for all local development using web sockets or am I missing something?

Comment: AFAIK, yes, you need a secure connection with WebSockets. Can't you generate a self-signed certificate and add it among the trusted certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need SSL/TLS to use WebSockets unless you are connecting from a page that is also using SSL/TLS -- I'm looking t such a page right now and it works fine. Do the sample apps (Sample.html and JSONViewer.html) in the Leap Motion SDK work for you?

Comment: Great to hear that it should work. However, I'm getting "WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:6437/v6.json' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400" for whatever Leap apps I'm trying to run locally, including Sample.html and JSONViewer.html. I don't have any funky firewall  running so no idea what's causing it.. Any suggestions for where to look are very welcome!

Comment: ..forgot that I'm in China and have a VPN running in the background.. D'oh!